# How do I do a basic indexed sum in Cloudant map/reduce?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant

I have a [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) database containing the following documents

```
{"test": 1, "value": 10}
{"test": 1, "value": 20}
{"test": 2, "value": 100}
{"test": 2, "value": 200}
```

I want to create a view that takes the sum of all the values for a given test. So the view would contain

```
{"rows":[
    {"key":1,"value": 30}
    {"key":2,"value": 300}
]}
```

(i.e. 30 = 10 + 20 and 300 = 100 + 200)

What is the correct way to do this in Cloudant?

So far I have tried the following mapper

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.test, doc.value);
}
```

with the built-in `_sum` reducer, but that gives

```
{"rows":[
    {"key":null,"value":330}
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the group=true param on your reduce.

"If you want to return results per key, use group=true. group=true is an invalid for a map-only or reduce=false view, you will get an error if you try to group a non-reduced view."

https://cloudant.com/for-developers/views/

Comment: That's it. I was confused because I'm used to working with map/reduce in Hadoop where reducing by key is the default behavior.